# IndexError: list index out of range while using reduceByKey operation on pyspark shell

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Goal: To find highest video category from the youtube data set

Using : Pyspark shell

Expected : category with number of times it appears

Actual : Error while using reduceBykey as IndexError: list index out of range

I have tried the below code:

```
data="/Users/sk/Documents/GitRepository/Udemy_BigData_spark/1.txt"
input = sc.textFile(data)
results = input.map(lambda x: (x.split(‘\t')[3].encode("utf-8").replace('"', '').replace("'", '')))results.take(20)
```

This gives below results:

```
['Comedy', 'Comedy', 'Entertainment', 'People & Blogs', 'People &
Blogs', 'Music', 'Comedy', 'People & Blogs', 'Entertainment',
'Entertainment', 'Entertainment', 'Entertainment', 'Entertainment',
'Entertainment', 'Entertainment', 'Entertainment', 'Entertainment',
'Entertainment', 'Entertainment', 'Entertainment']


results=results.map(lambda x: (x,1))
```

This gives below result:

```
[('Comedy', 1), ('Comedy', 1), ('Entertainment', 1), ('People & Blogs', 1), ('People & Blogs', 1), ('Music', 1), ('Comedy', 1), ('People & Blogs', 1), ('Entertainment', 1), ('Entertainment', 1), ('Entertainment', 1), ('Entertainment', 1), ('Entertainment', 1), ('Entertainment', 1), ('Entertainment', 1), ('Entertainment', 1), ('Entertainment', 1), ('Entertainment', 1), ('Entertainment', 1), ('Entertainment', 1)]


results=results.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)    
results.take(20)
```

This gives a huge error :(

I want it to show me the result like below:

```
(179049,Music), (127674,Entertainment), (87818,Comedy), (73293,Film &
Animation), (67329,Sports)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code I wrote is in scala;

```
val ds = Seq("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "D", 
             "E", "F", "G", "A")
  .toDF.as[String].map(x => (x, 1))
ds.groupByKey(x => x._1)
  .reduceGroups((l, r) => (l._1, l._2+r._2))
  .show
```

Outputs:

```
+-----+------------------------------+
|value|ReduceAggregator(scala.Tuple2)|
+-----+------------------------------+
|    F|                        [F, 1]|
|    E|                        [E, 1]|
|    B|                        [B, 2]|
|    D|                        [D, 1]|
|    C|                        [C, 2]|
|    A|                        [A, 3]|
|    G|                        [G, 1]|
+-----+------------------------------+
```

Comment: hey Elior, I am looking for python code. With scala I could get this working. But Assignment is to work with pyspark :(